# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Сначала я запятую не поставила, а потом засомневалась: "Серый с белым(,) пушистый кот".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос. действительно, хорош, но именно тем, что ответ на него не так прост. как кажется. Действительно, определения в данном предложении неоднородны, так как   характеризуют предмет с разных сторон: по цвету и "по пушистости". Но! однородные определения могут характеризовать предмет также с разных сторон, если при этом **в условиях контекста** они объединяются каким-нибудь общим признаком (сходством производимого ими впечатления, внешним видом и т.д.): Он протягивал мне красную, опухшую, грязную руку;  В густых, темных волосах блестели седые пряди. Представьте, что вы говорите о коте, хвастаясь им, любуясь. Правда, интонация изменилась? Пауза появилась? Т.е. при определении однородности -неоднородности определений роль автора текста очень велика. И является определяющим критерием. Конечно, если это предложение из упражнения, то по формальным признакам лучше всего дать именно такой ответ, какой дан выше. Но если Вам важно передать смысл, и Вы знаете, что именно хотите сказать - послушайте интонацию и сделайте вывод! Далеко не все знаки препинания определяются интонацией и соответствуют паузе. Но при решении вопроса. однородные определения или нет, интонация и авторский замысел очень важны! Не зря подобные случаи в тесты (хорошие тесты) не вставляют.

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос. Давайте рассуждать. Если бы было "серый пушистый кот", то запятая не ставилась бы. Серый с белым = окрас. Исходя из такой логики запятая здесь не нужна.